# Trouble using Yahoo search API

Tags: php, json, api, search, yahoo

I am currently working on a project with a good buddy of mine and we have run into a bit of trouble and we were wondering if you guys could help? We are currently using yahoos search engine API and it is returning the results in JSON. Is it possible to make these links "clickable"?

Comment: what do the results look like?

Comment: Short answer: yes. How? Need a bit more data. What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Showing what you have done will help the community answer your question.

Comment: This question needs more detail. Are you doing your link construction server via using PHP, or client side using javascript? What to the results look like? How do you want the link to behave (ie do you want to use an A tag or another element with an onclick handler?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, you are looking for something like this :

```
$yahooResponse = Yahoo response JSON data;
$linkUrl = $yahooResponse->url;
echo '<a href="$linkUrl">Clik here</a>';
```